# Ho to test file upload in Ruby on Rails 6 with minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have controller method like this:

```rb
# POST /v1/scans
  def create
    p params
    uploaded_file = params["pm_file"]
    filename      = uploaded_file.original_filename
    content       = uploaded_file.read
    parser = ParserStrategy.parser_for filename
    file_scan = parser.parse_content content, filename, @api_token.organisation

    data = {'scan.id': file_scan.id.to_s}
    render json: data, status: :created 
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error e.message
    Rails.logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
  end
```

The file upload works fine. If I test it with CURL like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer QGoEUTK5htI6IT1zyLgKWPqBxv1EXrf7ApSFuuSi" -X POST http://localhost:3000/v1/scans -F pm_file=@composer.json
```

I'm getting the expected results and the parameters output looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"pm_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f914bae9708 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ng/h_lxfcf13m71_kgr70_f79hr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20200521-75565-r5a4k1.json>, @original_filename="composer.json", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pm_file\"; filename=\"composer.json\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}
<ActionController::Parameters {"pm_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f914bae9708 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ng/h_lxfcf13m71_kgr70_f79hr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20200521-75565-r5a4k1.json>, @original_filename="composer.json", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pm_file\"; filename=\"composer.json\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">, "controller"=>"v1/scans", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

I can clearly see that `pm_file` is an Object of the type UploadedFile. Now I would like to write an automated test for it. Did so with minitest:

```rb
test "should return 201 because valid request" do
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/composer/composer.json"
  composer_file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(file_path, 'application/json', false)
  post v1_scans_url, params: { pm_file: composer_file }, headers: { "Authorization" => "Bearer #{@token}" }, as: :json
  assert_response 201
end
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work. Then I fire the test the parameters output looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"pm_file"=>{"original_filename"=>"composer.json", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007fd2a11dff30>", "content_type"=>"application/json"}, "scan"=>{"pm_file"=>{"original_filename"=>"composer.json", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007fd2a11dff30>", "content_type"=>"application/json"}}}
```

Now the `pm_file` is not an Object of the type UploadedFile anymore, it's a Hash. And the code is failing with:

```
undefined method `original_filename' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007fd2859c2278>
```

The same happens with `fixture_file_upload`. This test brings exactly the same result:

```rb
test "should return 201 because valid request" do
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/composer/composer.json"
  composer_file = fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/composer/composer.json",'application/json')
  post v1_scans_url, params: { pm_file: composer_file }, headers: { "Authorization" => "Bearer #{@token}" }, as: :json
  assert_response 201
end
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to test a file upload in Rails 6 correctly?

Comment: `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` only works when you are sending a `multipart/form-data` request. If you are sending files in JSON you need to Base64 encode the file as JSON has no binary type. Sending files to APIs is a whole topic in of itself. https://itnext.io/uploading-files-to-your-rails-api-6b293a4a5c90

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After removing `as: :json` it worked like expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to send the file via JSON. After removing the `as: :json` snippet at the end of the post, it worked like expected. So this test here works like expected for file uploads with Minitest:

```rb
test "should return 201 because valid request" do
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/composer/composer.json"
  composer_file = fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/composer/composer.json",'application/json')
  post v1_scans_url, params: { pm_file: composer_file }, headers: { "Authorization" => "Bearer #{@token}" }
  assert_response 201
end
```